# How to calculate cumulative amount from Opportunities and child account Opportunities on the Parent Account?

Tags: apex

want to create a trigger on Account  where i can make sum of all amounts of opportunity related list of the current account and all its child Accounts.whenever the record is created or updated

Class code:

```
public with sharing class Amountopportunities 
{
    public void onBeforeInsert(List < Account > newacc)
    {   List<Account>acclist =new List<Account>();
        Double x=0;
        for(Account acc:[Select Id,ParentId,(Select Amount From Opportunities),(Select Id,Total_Amount__c From ChildAccounts) From Account where id IN : newacc ])
        {

              for (Opportunity objOpp : acc.Opportunities)
                {               
                       if(objOpp.Amount != null)
                         x += objOpp.Amount;
                }
              for(Account acc2:acc.ChildAccounts)
                {
                    if(acc2.Total_Amount__c!=null)
                        x+=acc2.Total_Amount__c;
                        System.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@'+x);

                }
                acc.Total_Amount__c=x;
               acclist.add(acc);                
        }


    }   

}
```

Comment: have you tried any thing?

Comment: Account is the Parent and Opportunity is the Child. Why don't you use Rollup Summary Field for your requirement...? Why Trigger...? Any reasons?

Comment: @kurunve pointed out why we cant use roll up.
We need to sum opportunities of child accounts

Comment: i want to use trigger because i want to perform the action on updation of any field of the account

Comment: from above question there is one requirement also tha the amount field of parent account should also get updated automatically

Answer (score 1):

**Edited Answer:**

You can use below approach.
 1. To calculate the sum of amount from child opportunities create a Roll-Up Summary field on Account Let's say **Opportunity Amount**.  (No code required)
Doing so you will get sum of opportunity on each account.
 2. Create another field on Account which will store the sum of Amount from **Opportunity Amount** of child Accounts Lets say this field as **Child Accounts Sum**.
 3. Create a formula field to add **Opportunity Amount** and **Child Accounts Sum** let's say this field is **Grand Total**
4. You can write trigger for calculating sum of  **Child Accounts Sum** or you can use app exchange solution https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI

Comment: are you sure that that would work for all child account opportunities?

Comment: i am not sure but i need the solution of that

Comment: Downvoted... :( Have you even  tried the above suggestion ?